# Open3d : How to select appropriate plane using RANSAC

Tags: python, image-segmentation, open3d, ransac

I'm working on a point cloud using o3d and I want to do segmentation and extract objects from the point cloud. First I want to remove walls, floors etc. so I'm using RANSAC for this.

The thing is segment_plane function select the biggest segment found and it is not always the one I want to remove. I used a loop to select the n biggest segment but for example if the 1st segment that I want to keep has points that could have been in the 3rd segment that I want to remove, they won't be part of that 3rd segment as already in first one.
One solution could be to merge the 1st segment that I want to keep with the rest but then RANSAC will find again that segment so it is not working.

How to select the segment to remove and not the biggest one using RANSAC in open3d ? (using python)

Comment: If you want to stick to RANSAC, I guess you'll have to look for its code in open3d, and modify it to have some initial set of points which belongs to the floors/walls you want to delete

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect multiple planes, you can use this [repo](https://github.com/yuecideng/Multiple_Planes_Detection) that also uses open3d. After detecting planes, Since I couldn't figure out your removal criteria, I will just let user to pick a point from the point cloud and remove the plane that selected point belongs to, you can edit this criteria of course. I will explain step by step.

1. Read the point cloud data.

   ```
   points = ReadPlyPoint('fragment.ply')
   ```
2. Pre-process the data

   ```
   points = RemoveNan(points)
   points = DownSample(points,voxel_size=0.025) 
   points = RemoveNoiseStatistical(points, nb_neighbors=50, std_ratio=0.5)
   ```
3. Detect multiple planes

   ```
   results = DetectMultiPlanes(points, min_ratio=0.05, threshold=0.005, iterations=500)
   ```
4. Generate a colored point cloud, so user can select the plane she wants to remove.

   ```
   planes = []
   colors = []

   for _, plane in results:
       r = random.random()
       g = random.random()
       b = random.random()

       color = np.zeros((plane.shape[0], plane.shape[1]))
       color[:, 0] = r
       color[:, 1] = g
       color[:, 2] = b

       planes.append(plane)
       colors.append(color)

   planes = np.concatenate(planes, axis=0)
   colors = np.concatenate(colors, axis=0)
   ```
5. Get the point user selected

   ```
   selected_points_id = DrawResult(planes, colors)
   ```
6. Reprocess the data to remove selected planes

   ```
   result_pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
   planes_n = []
   colors_n = []

   # this will only remove one plane. a point may belong to several different planes, so you can make this a number
   # or change it however you want
   found = False
   for point in selected_points_id:
       # for each selected point iterate through the planes
       for _, plane in results:
           if planes[point] in plane and not found:
               found = True
               continue
           else:
               r = random.random()
               g = random.random()
               b = random.random()

               color = np.zeros((plane.shape[0], plane.shape[1]))
               color[:, 0] = r
               color[:, 1] = g
               color[:, 2] = b

               planes_n.append(plane)
               colors_n.append(color)

   planes_n = np.concatenate(planes_n, axis=0)
   colors_n = np.concatenate(colors_n, axis=0)

   result_pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
   result_pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(planes_n)
   result_pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(colors_n)
   ```

After this point you can save it or do whatever you want.

I also want to share a few remarks that could make things faster.

- Probably you would have less planes than the points. So checking the points a plane has and comparing if the plane has the point you wish to remove is costly. Instead, you can set a threshold, say 0.1, and find the distance of your point with respect to all planes you have detected and remove the closest one if the distance is less than your threshold value.
- Of course, this code is slow because it process the data twice. However, if you have an selection criteria instead of letting user to choose which plane she wishes to remove, you could process the data only once.
- If you have problems with 2 plane being too close, even there is only one plane, you can consider a bigger voxel downsample parameter, yet be careful to not to use a large voxel down sample parameter since this may harm plane detection.

And finally here are the results using open3d dataset fragments.ply.

[image: Planes detected]

Choosing a point in GUI:
[image]

And the result:

[image]

Comment: If you need a C++ version, please let me now. I am planning to add this, but not a priority at the moment.